# CSS Less-Could not find the class in bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I just start learning css less and I'm using Less v1.5.0 and WinLess to compile the less file. I have a bunch of code as below:

```
@import "bootstrap.css";
@import "bootstrap-responsive.css";

.test{
    .well;
}
```

but WinLess give me an error says .well is not defined. I was expecting it to pull out the content of well class from bootstrap.css. So where did I do wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS files are not processed by LESS when you import them, therefore you cannot use their classes as mixing.
Import them as LESS files:

```
@import (less) "bootstrap.css";
@import (less) "bootstrap-responsive.css";

.test{
    .well;
}
```

Read more [here](http://lesscss.org/#-importing) (enter Language -> Importing).

Comment: Hi Michal, I tried but it says could not find bootstrap.less file, should I also change the extension of bootstrap.css file to bootstrap.less?

Comment: Oops, the link I posted seems not to point into the right place, something's broken on the website. See my edited answer. If you don't want to import `.less` files, you can use `(less)` as shown in  my edited answer to tell LESS that you want your `.css` files to be interpreted as if they were `.less` files.